# When defining 'Set set = new HashSet()', is set an instance of interface or class Set?

Tags: java, collections

In Java, 'Set' and 'List' are interfaces derived from 'Collection' interface.
If we use the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SetExample{

    public stactic void main(String[] args){
      Set set = new HashSet();
      //do something .....
    }

}
```

Is there a class 'Set' in "Collection" API that we are creating an object ('set') of? or we are instantiating a interface 'Set'?

Am really confused.......:O

Comment: Make sure to provide the generic type arguments to generic types otherwise you will end up with raw types and lose most type checks done by the compiler

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`java.util.Set` is an interface, not a class.  So

```
Set set = new HashSet();
```

creates an object that is a `HashSet` instance, and assigns a reference to that object to a variable whose type is `Set`.  This works because the `HashSet` class *implements* the `Set` interface.  On the other hand:

```
Set set = new Set();
```

gives a compilation error because you cannot create an instance of an interface.

An Java interface is essentially a contract between an implementation (a class) and the things that use it.  It says what the names and signatures of a conforming object's methods are, but nothing about the object's state or how its methods work.

(Just to confuse things a bit ... Java also allows you to write something like this:

```
Set set = new Set() {
    // attributes and methods go here
};
```

This is does not create an "instance" of the `Set` interface *per se* ... because that doesn't make sense.  Rather, it declares and instantiates an *anonymous class* that *implements* the `Set` interface.)

Comment: I came here to find out the difference between `Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>();` vs `HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>();`. So is there a difference?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some pointers:

- [What are Interfaces?](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) (Sun Java
  Tutorial)
- [The Set Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) (Sun Java
  Tutorial)
- [The Collection Interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html) (Sun
  Java Tutorial)
- [Interfaces](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) (Sun Java Tutorial)

You should also read [Effective Java by Joshua Bloch](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), especially item 52: "Refer to objects by their interfaces" (There's a small snippet viewable [here](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780137150021/ch08lev1sec8))

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Set` interface provides the loose coupling with `java.util.HashSet` object. So developer can use the `java.util.Set` reference for another `java.util.Set` interface family object.

Answer (score 0):

The reference `set` is of type `java.util.Set` which is an `interface`. Although it actually points to an object of type `java.util.HashSet`. (polymorphic)

Answer (score 0):

In API you get a bunch of interfaces that hides the implementation. e.g. Set allows you 
to hide any implementation, for which HashSet is one of.