# 'Set = new HashSet' or 'HashSet = new Hashset'?

Tags: java, generics, collections, constructor, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List versus ArrayList variable type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062982/list-versus-arraylist-variable-type)

I'm intialising a `HashSet` like so in my program:

`Set<String> namesFilter = new HashSet<String>();`

Is this functionally any different if I initilise like so?

`HashSet<String> namesFilter = new HashSet<String>();`

I've read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html) about the collections interface, and I understand interfaces (well, except their use here). I've read this [excerpt](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780137150021/ch08lev1sec8) from Effective Java, and I've read this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715209/when-defining-set-set-new-hashset-is-set-an-instance-of-interface-or-clas), but I feel none the wiser.

Is there a best practice in Java, and if so, why? My intuition is that it makes casting to a different type of `Set` easier in my first example. But then again, you'd only be casting to something that was a collection, and you could convert it by re-constructing it.

Comment: I prefer using the interface.  If you already know all the arguments, what's the question?  What's the problem?

Comment: See [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: @duffymo I've heard the arguments, but they haven't helped me understand. The answer here and the answer in the proposed dupe make sense however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's better practice to use the interface over the concrete type, i.e.

```
Set<String> strings = new HashSet<String>();
```

By doing this, you commit yourself to only using the functionality provided by the `Set` interface. This makes it easier to swap out the kind of set you're using at a later date if you decide that you want different performance characteristics (e.g. if you wanted to use a `TreeSet` instead) without worrying about breaking your code.